# Filter rows with minimum values groupwise in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I need to select only the rows that have the minimum price:

example:

```
ORIGIN   | DESTINA. | PRICE
____________________________
BOG      | MAD      |  1500
BOG      | MAD      |  750
BOG      | MAD      |  1250
BOG      | MAD      |  1350
BOG      | MIA      |   450
```

So in this example, what I would like to get is only the third AND sixth row:

```
ORIGIN   | DESTINA. | PRICE
____________________________
BOG      | MAD      | 750
BOG      | MIA      | 450
```

Using python, how can I get this final table?

Comment: only change `max` to `min` or `idxmax` to `idxmin`

Answer (score 9):

Using `GroupBy` + `transform` with `min`:

```
df = df[df['PRICE'] == df.groupby('ORIGIN')['PRICE'].transform('min')]
```

This will keep duplicate groupwise minima. If you *don't* want to keep duplicates, you can sort, then drop duplicates:

```
df = df.sort_values('PRICE').drop_duplicates('ORIGIN')
```